# Do minions benefit from the Mountain Drake buff?

Tags: league-of-legends

The mountain drake gives additional damage against epic monsters and turrets.

> "Earthen Arms" grants 10/20/30% additional damage (based on stacks;
>   +50% if they have Mark of the Elder Dragon) as true damage to epic monsters and turrets.

Does this damage apply to minion damage? I'm presuming that it does not as they do not carry the buff.

What about Zz'Rott portals? Do the spawned minions do additional damage to turrets?

Comment: I don't have any source except intuition and logic, but I'd say it's very safe to assume no units without the buff shown will have the effects of the buff. Ie a minion won't show the buff when you click on it, so I'd say it wouldn't have the effect.

Comment: hey you used drake/dragon correctly respective of the monsters. GJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No dragon only buffs champions.

For additional context, this is buff applied by killing the appropriate dragons
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Slayer

> Dragon Slayer is a non-transferable, stacking, neutral buff awarded to the team slaying Dragon Dragon on Summoner's Rift. Each elemental buff can stack up to to three times. The effects are amplified by 50% with an Elder Dragon kill.

Comment: If you could add a little more info, or a source, that would dramatically improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: @Dragonrage added extra context.